# Regex that captures and filters the "steps" strings that have only one sole number at the early part

Tags: python, pandas, regex

So I have a pandas.Series as such

```
s = pd.Series(['1-Onboarding + Retorno', '1.1-Onboarding escolha de bot',
                  '2-Seleciona produto', '3-Informa localizacao e cpf',
                  '3.1-CPF valido (V.2.0)', '3.2-Obtencao de CEP'],name = 'Steps')

0           1-Onboarding + Retorno
1    1.1-Onboarding escolha de bot
2              2-Seleciona produto
3      3-Informa localizacao e cpf
4           3.1-CPF valido (V.2.0)
5              3.2-Obtencao de CEP
```

The idea here is to "filter" the df so I gather only the strings with the a unique number.

```
s = pd.Series(['1-Onboarding + Retorno',
                  '2-Seleciona produto', '3-Informa localizacao e cpf'],name = 'Steps')

0         1-Onboarding + Retorno
1            2-Seleciona produto
2    3-Informa localizacao e cpf
Name: Steps, dtype: object
```

Any ideas on how I could do that? I am having difficulties formulating the regex. I know I should use to formulate such filter in Pandas.

```
s.str.contains('',regex = True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `str.contains` here:

```py
df_out = s[s["Steps"].str.contains(r'^\d+-', regex=True)]
```

The resulting output data frame `df_out` will contain only steps value which begin with a major version (integer) number.

Comment: Use the pattern: `^(?:9|\d{2,})-` to match 9 or higher

Comment: Perfect I needed to formulate both in another issue

Answer (score 1):

you can use this

```
l=[]
for i in range(len(s)):
        if '.' not in s[i] :
            l.append(s[i])
new_s= pd.Series(l,name = 'Steps')
```

out:

```
0         1-Onboarding + Retorno
1            2-Seleciona produto
2    3-Informa localizacao e cpf
```